# How do I set the query location when using bigQuery.jobs.insert API

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using bigQuery.jobs.insert [API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) and I need to set the location of the query

In bigQuery.jobs.query [API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) I see I can set the location as follow

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/[PROJECTID]/queries' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"query":"select 5","location":"asia-northeast1"}' \
  --compressed
```

But in bigQuery.jobs.insert I see no such option, I tried this:

`"resource": {
    "projectId": "project",
    "configuration": {
      "query": {
        "query": "SELECT 5",
        "useLegacySql": false,
        "location": "asia-northeast1",
        "defaultDataset": {
          "datasetId": "ds"
        },
        "jobReference": {
           "location": "asia-northeast1"
        }
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: Just put in the configuration object the key `location`.

Comment: I did But it still execute it in US 
"jobReference": {
    "projectId": "mydata-1470162410749",
    "jobId": "job_RjavB_rs1smGyQJOc7ndK3rRI1FE",
    "location": "US"
  }

Comment: not there, in the job configuration object. What programming language, sdk, library you are using? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#specifying_your_location

Comment: I'm using javascript language

Comment: sorry not configuration object into the `jobReference` you need to add according to API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs

and https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#specifying_your_location

When you use the API, specify your region in the `location` property in the `jobReference` section of the job resource.

Comment: Yes, I read the API as I provided it in my original questions, For clarification, I edit the JSON I'm sending to the API but no matter what I do the execution is done in US. Can you provide a working JSON payload I can use?

Comment: Add a `jobReference.location` key to the top (resource) level.

Comment: Perfect, Voting up on this one, I guess Google API is not 100% clear at least not to me